# Disable floating point exceptions during a single function

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe6

Can I wrap my Delphi code in the undocumented `{$finiteFloat OFF|ON}` compiler directive like below to disable floating point exceptions during a function?

```
{$finiteFloat OFF}
a := 5.0;
b := 0.0;
c := a/b;  // do not raise exception here!
{$finiteFloat ON}
```

I know I can in the case of constants with {$J} but i don't think {$finiteFloat} can do it because it's scope is global. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: What does this directive do? Isn't it .net only? If you want to mask floating point exceptions, use the RTL functions to do that.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Floating_Point_Exception_Checking_(Delphi). It is undocumented since XE2 though.

Comment: {$finiteFloat} turns off floating points errors
{$J+} will allow you to change your constants at run time
I believe both can be dangerous and would rather avoid them.

Comment: Why don't use {`$J+`}? How it relates?

Comment: It's not related to his question at all, it's a statement of opinion.  I edited the question because questions should be asked in a way that other people on the site can find them. I change the question title as it made no sense.  Also the text of the question should state what you are trying to do. Really people.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This compiler directive applies only to the now defunct .net compiler, which explains why it is not documented. So, this directive has no effect in your program since you are not using the .net compiler. To mask floating point exceptions with your compiler, call [`SetExceptionMask`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Math.SetExceptionMask).

This [article](http://hallvards.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/dn4dp16-net-only-floating-point.html) from Hallvard Vassbotn shows the following example code which makes this point:

```
{$IFDEF CLR}
  {$FINITEFLOAT OFF}
{$ELSE}
  Math.SetExceptionMask([exInvalidOp, exDenormalized, exZeroDivide, exOverflow, 
    exUnderflow, exPrecision]);
{$ENDIF}
One := 0;
Two := 42;
Three := Two / One; // Returns +Inf, no exception raised
```

Note how Hallvard only used `$FINITEFLOAT` with the .net compiler. The article also explains why this directive is needed on .net.

Comment: Here is a link to Hallvards blog about this directive and the .net compiler: http://hallvards.blogspot.se/2007/09/dn4dp16-net-only-floating-point.html.

Comment: @LURD Thanks, I had found it at the same time!